# Prediction of dress size by body measurment

Tags: machine-learning, business, classification, large-datasets, deep-learning

Hope you all doing well. I am making an E-commerce project where there is need of recommendation system that would recommend dress size as S(small), M(medium), L(Large), XL(Extra large) ,2XL on the basis of body measurements like height, chest size, arm length, etc. I am trying to find a dataset that would be used to train ML model to recommend dress size but I am still not able to find one. Please anyone could suggest me a dataset or any other method for size recommendation system.